# script doesn't work in the server, but working on localhost

Tags: php

So the problem is that I got a mistake - *Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...*. There is a millions of solution on the website that told exactly what is the problem, and the question is not about it. But the problem that I don't get that mistake during test on my localhost, everything work fine without mistake, but as soon I upload the scrip on the server it gave me this mistake. So the question what is the diferent between server and localhost?

Comment: Check same config settings and versions in both local and server

Comment: How should we help if you don't post your code? Most likely this has to do with some generally included script and output buffering turned on locally, but not on the remote system. A wild guess: remove all closing php tags from your code (`?>`). They are note required at all and can easily cause such issues with trailing spaces after them getting sent as html markup thus triggering headers to be sent as well.

Comment: @arkascha I'm sorry but I just ask general question not about my specific problem, I just want to know why it is so different, since mistake in code localhost must to do the same that server but it don't do it.

Comment: Certainly the systems will behave different if configured different, won't they?

Comment: @arkascha agree, i just trying to check the interesting answer about UTF8 without BOM...

Comment: @arkascha agree that configuration can make a huge sense here, but the mistake with header is mistake that make page work or not, don't you think so?

Comment: Well, the questions is _why_ the headers are sent out early, assuming that you do not do that by purpose in your code. So there must be some difference between your local setup and the remote system that causes some output to be sent which will inevitable also sent out headers automatically. Once that happens you will get the warning above. That is why I mentioned the typical culprits of using closing php tags at the end of files and output buffering being configured different.

Comment: Sorry, just realize a glitch in my advise about closing php tags above: I obviously only refer to the closing php tags at the end of files. Not such embedded in the middle of some view template. Closing tags at the end of files should not be used, they only cause problems and have no effect anyway (since the file ends afterwards).

Comment: @arkascha check the code that i include

Comment: @alex_mike Sorry, can't spot any code.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your help, I found the mistake, it was just an empty string before <?php tag

Answer (score 1):

open your file with text editor like notepad++, then from encoding tab choose "UTF8 without BOM" then your code should work.BOM character is a character that you cant see but will be sent to header and and cause your this problem.

Comment: well..i had this problem a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually little or no difference. It depends on the OS both are running on and configuration settings of both. Some rules are enforced on linux which are not enforced on windows for example. The best is to try to understand the OS so you'll be able to configure them very well.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet is that the error reporting level is different in `php.ini`.

On your localhost you may have notices and warnings turned off, while they are enabled on the server.

In that case, an additional unwanted output will be produced, and this output generates the unwanted headers.